# How to get print dialog without openning new window in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have some html data and want to print them

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.write(data);
w.print();
w.close();
```

It works but I don't want to open the window

Is there a way to get print dialog (with print preview) without openning the window in browser ?

Or - somehow make it invisible for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) on an `<iframe>` and use CSS to hide it from end users:

```html
<iframe name="foo"></iframe>
```

```css
iframe {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
// Empty string passed as first argument means to open a blank page.
// Second argument is the iframe's name attribute.
const w = window.open('', 'foo');
w.document.write(data);
w.print();
w.close();
```

Comment: it works, thanks. You just need a closing ifram tag

Comment: Right, good catch.